# A webtoon about a princess getting kidnapped by her ex?

Tags: story-identification, webcomics

It happened in space. The princess was kidnapped by a group and they wanted to blackmail the queen, then they found out she looks like their friend and one of the members of the group's girlfriend who killed the boy's sister in a war and then disappeared and everyone thought she was dead. Then the queen came after them.

The boy had a scar in his face, the girl's hair was silver and there was two aliens in their group, one pink and she like to dress fancy and the other was blue and had a long neck. It was on [WEBTOON Canvas](https://m.webtoons.com/en/challenge).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you watch this?  Do you remember where?

Comment: Around a year age before sth happened that deletd all my search history and a used to read it on webtoon

Comment: Do you remember the genre (the banner would be color coded to match)? What about the thumbnail? Or even the art style (manga vs cartoony, full color vs not, etc)?

Comment: Hi, it was full color, the genre was fantasy and